# Module not found Error when running pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

This is how my files are organized:

```
.(root)
├── __init__.py
├── tests/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── animation_tests/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_other_animations.py
└── src/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── alien_onslaught.py
    ├── animations/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── other_animations.py
    └── utils/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── animation_constants.py
```

Inside the test_other_animations.py I am importing three classes like this:

`from src.animations.other_animations import DestroyAnim, MissileEx, Immune`

The import statement that is inside the module other_animations.py triggers the error when I am running the test:

```
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\Rux\Desktop\Programming\Projects\AlienOnslaught\alien_onslaught\tests\animation_tests\test_other_animations.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Users\Rux\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_other_animations.py:7: in <module>
from src.animations.other_animations import DestroyAnim, MissileEx, Immune
> ..\..\src\animations\other_animations.py:10: in <module>
from utils.animation_constants import (
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils`
```

I have tried to modify the import statement inside the other_animations.py into:

```
from ..utils.animation_constants import (
destroy_frames,
missile_ex_frames,
alien_immune_frames,
)
```

And the tests are now working but when I run the main file alien_onslaught.py (which starts the game) I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rux\Desktop\Programming\Projects\AlienOnslaught\Alien-Onslaught-main\src\alien_onslaught.py", line 21, in <module>
    from game_logic.collision_detection import CollisionManager
  File "C:\Users\Rux\Desktop\Programming\Projects\AlienOnslaught\Alien-Onslaught-main\src\game_logic\collision_detection.py", line 8, in <module>
    from entities.projectiles import Missile
  File "C:\Users\Rux\Desktop\Programming\Projects\AlienOnslaught\Alien-Onslaught-main\src\entities\projectiles.py", line 16, in <module>
    from animations.other_animations import MissileEx
  File "C:\Users\Rux\Desktop\Programming\Projects\AlienOnslaught\Alien-Onslaught-main\src\animations\other_animations.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..utils.animation_constants import (
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

So the problem happens always when I am importing a class or something from a module inside my tests and that module has also an import statement.

I have tried different imports, relative, absolute and still the same results.

Comment: I solved it a similar issue by removing the `__init__.py` file in the root directory

Comment: I tried that too, not success